# How to pre-select first radio button in Angular?

Tags: angular

I need to show a dynamic list of radiobuttons, where the first one must always be selected.
I made it with:

```
[checked]="i === 0"
```

but once I added:

```
[(ngModel)]="item.modifType"
```

The first RB wasnt selected again and just got the last RB selected. I need to keep ngModel.
So, what can I do?
I already tried not using [checked]="i === 0" and just comparing ngmodel with the value of RB.
Still dont work.

This is my RB list:

```
    <div class="card-body">
               <div *ngFor='let item of items; let i = index'>
                    <input type="radio" id="{{ item.id }}" name="modifType" value="{{ item.modifType }}" 
                    [checked]="idx === 0" 
                    [(ngModel)]="item.modifType" (change)='radioChecked( item.id, i )'>
                    <label class="form-check-label"> &nbsp; {{ item.modifType }} </label>
               </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the rest of code:

```
export class ModifComponent implements OnInit {

    items: any = { ErrorDesc: '0' };
    error = false;
    msgError: string;
    modifType: any;

sModifType() {
        this._sharedService.sModifType().subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                if (response.Status === 'success' || response.StatusMessage === 'success') {
                    this.items = JSON.parse(response.Data);
                } else if (response.Status === 'error' || response.StatusMessage === 'error') {
                    this.items = { ErrorDesc: response.Message };
                    this._sharedService.saveError(response.Data, 20, 'modification').subscribe((data2: any) => {
                        console.log(data2);
                    });
                }
            },
            (error: any) => {
                this.items = { ErrorDesc: error };
                this.msgError = error.message;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work guys, thank you very much for your help.

This was what worked for me:

I removed the `[checked]="idx === 0"`

and modified this `[value]="item.modifType"`  // added the [ ] to value

and this `[ngModel]="userSelection.chosen"`   // ngModel only with [ ], to give option from TS

Then in TS file I added:

```
export class ModifComponent implements OnInit {
    items: any = { ErrorDesc: '0' };
    error = false;
    msgError: string;
    modifType: any;
    userSelection = {                   // this is new
        chosen: 'Bank Account'
    };
```

Being 'chosen' the value of input I wanted to select.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is use `[(ngModel)]="item.modifType"` change it to use `[value]="item.modifType"`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u7aucf

```
 <div class="card-body">
               <div *ngFor='let item of items; let i = index'>
                    {{i==0}}
                    <input type="radio" id="{{ item.id }}" name="modifType" [value]="item.modifType" 
                    [checked]="i === 0">
                    <label class="form-check-label"> &nbsp; {{ item.modifType }} </label>
               </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I do that I get the same result :c I just got the last RB selected, not the first

Answer (score 1):

Try actually setting the initial value for the binding. In the Angular markup, you're using

```
[(ngModel)]="item.modifType"
```

You're defining `items` as an *any* object and `modifType` as an *any*, but you don't specify `modifType` as actually being a property of `item`.

Rather, in the markup, use the following:

```
<div class="card-body">
           <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
                <input type="radio" id="{{ item.id }}" name="modifType" value="ModifType Value" [(ngModel)]="item.modifType" (change)="radioChecked( item.id, i )">
                <label class="form-check-label"> &nbsp; {{ item.modifType }} </label>
           </div>
</div>
```

And in the component, use the following. Note the added `modifType` on the `items` definition, making it an array to iterate through, setting a value to match the value property in your markup, and then later commenting out the subsequent `modifType` line.

Because you specify the value of the `item.modifType`, it informs Angular which is selected from the start. Also, because you used the value of `item.modifType`, that causes a circular loop (something has to provide the value to for `item.modifType` and it can't simply be the current uninitialized value, or will will remain so).

You similarly refer to `item.id` in the markup, but don't actually define that anywhere, but presumably that may be populated in the remainder of the code you left unposted.

```
export class ModifComponent implements OnInit {

    items: any[] = [{ ErrorDesc: '0', modifType: 'ModifType Value' }];
    error = false;
    msgError: string;
    //modifType: any;

sModifType() {
        this._sharedService.sModifType().subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                if (response.Status === 'success' || response.StatusMessage === 'success') {
                    this.items = JSON.parse(response.Data);
                } else if (response.Status === 'error' || response.StatusMessage === 'error') {
                    this.items = { ErrorDesc: response.Message };
                    this._sharedService.saveError(response.Data, 20, 'modification').subscribe((data2: any) => {
                        console.log(data2);
                    });
                }
            },
            (error: any) => {
                this.items = { ErrorDesc: error };
                this.msgError = error.message;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a special variable call selectedRadioButton.
In your HTML you will do

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioButton" value="{{ item.id}}"/>
```

so this will always have the correct value.
in your subscribe you can catch the first value of the array and let the value of selectedRadioButton equal that id.